# AMP toolbox optimizer issue in nodejs

Tags: amp-html

I try to implement AMP optimizer using nodejs but i got invalidated amp page because it removes all amp extensions like amp-form, amp-list etc.. after optimization, this is something strange, when i use online playground https://toolbox-optimizer.glitch.me/, would be fine, it gives validated page, Problem appear if i use amp optimizer with nodejs, any idea. Thanks in advance

here it is what i tried

```
const AmpOptimizer = require('@ampproject/toolbox-optimizer');
const fs = require('fs').promises;

const validAmpTransformation = async () => {
    try {
        // create the AMP Optimizer instance
        const ampOptimizer = AmpOptimizer.create();
        const html = await fs.readFile('./amp-template.html', 'utf8');
        const transformedHtml = await ampOptimizer.transformHtml(html);
        await fs.writeFile('./optimizer.html', transformedHtml);
    } catch (error) {
        // send original html instead of any errors during optimization
    }
}

validAmpTransformation();
```

Comment: We had a similar problem. So now, as in your question, we use the online service. Less automated and not part of a workflow, but it works.

Comment: i will try other library like php, will see how that works, i am still thinking how online playground works and what they are doing inside

Comment: i have reported this in github https://github.com/ampproject/amp-toolbox/issues/958